# iframe dynamic height cross-domain using jquery.ba-postmessage

Tags: jquery, iframe, cross-domain, height

This is a question that I'm sure will help hundreds of people in the future. But the script is a little outside my jQuery ability. I have jQuery basic skills but can't work this out.

Basically I need an iFrame (which is hosted on a separate domain) to sit on my main website. I don't want to use an iFrame, but in my situation I have no choice! I need the iFrame to resize to the height of the body inside the iframe.

Currently using [Ben Alman jQuery postMessage plugin](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-postmessage/examples/iframe/), this looks like it can do it. But the current example has got unnecessary code in there which enables a toggle to resize the iFrame...

I do not need this toggle, all I need is for the iFrame to resize to the correct iframe content body height. I need the iframe height to adjust as the body height changes inside the iframe.

This is what I found so far...

**I have put this on the iframe content file**
This is on server: http://myiframecontent.com/

```
<script src="js/jquery.ba-postmessage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $(function(){
       // Get the parent page URL as it was passed in, for browsers that don't support
       // window.postMessage (this URL could be hard-coded).
       var parent_url = decodeURIComponent( document.location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) ),
         link;

       // The first param is serialized using $.param (if not a string) and passed to the
       // parent window. If window.postMessage exists, the param is passed using that,
       // otherwise it is passed in the location hash (that's why parent_url is required).
       // The second param is the targetOrigin.
       function setHeight() {
         $.postMessage({ if_height: $('body').outerHeight( true ) }, parent_url, parent );
       };

       // Now that the DOM has been set up (and the height should be set) invoke setHeight.
       setHeight();

       // And for good measure, let's listen for a toggle_content message from the parent.
       $.receiveMessage(function(e){
         if ( e.data === 'toggle_content' ) {
           link.triggerHandler( 'click' );
         }
       }, 'http://mywebsite.com' );
     });

</script>
```

**I have put this on my website**
This is on server: http://mywebsite.com/

```
<script src="js/jquery.ba-postmessage.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        // Keep track of the iframe height.
        var if_height,

        // Pass the parent page URL into the Iframe in a meaningful way (this URL could be
        // passed via query string or hard coded into the child page, it depends on your needs).

        src = 'http://myiframecontent.com/#' + encodeURIComponent( document.location.href ),

        // Append the Iframe into the DOM.
        iframe = $( '<iframe " src="' + src + '" width="1060" height="1000" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"><\/iframe>' )
            .appendTo( '#iframe' );

        // Setup a callback to handle the dispatched MessageEvent event. In cases where
        // window.postMessage is supported, the passed event will have .data, .origin and
        // .source properties. Otherwise, this will only have the .data property.
        $.receiveMessage(function(e){

        // Get the height from the passsed data.
        var h = Number( e.data.replace( /.*if_height=(\d+)(?:&|$)/, '$1' ) );

        if ( !isNaN( h ) && h > 0 && h !== if_height ) {
        // Height has changed, update the iframe.
            iframe.height( if_height = h );
        }

        // An optional origin URL (Ignored where window.postMessage is unsupported).
        }, 'http://myiframecontent.com/' );

        // And for good measure, let's send a toggle_content message to the child.
        $( '<a href="#">Show / hide Iframe content<\/a>' )
            .appendTo( '#nav' )
            .click(function(){
            $.postMessage( 'toggle_content', src, iframe.get(0).contentWindow );
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>

<div id="iframe" class="clear"></div>
```

Currently the above is returning the current width 1060px but not changing the height of my iframe to the height of the body inside my iframe?

And also the toggle button is being added into my site on my navigation div#nav. When all I need is the height.

Any help on this would be awesome as I can't find any working examples on the net, Thanks!

This is the [ba-postmessage.js](https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-postmessage/master/jquery.ba-postmessage.js) script.

Answer (score 0):

As you seem to want to get rid of the links, here is a working example with iframe contents that increases periodically through a `setInterval()`.

This should go to main website / server A: `http://mywebsite.com/`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Container on domain A (http://mywebsite.com/)</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-postmessage/master/jquery.ba-postmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){

        // Update this constant to match your IFrame (contents) URL (no '#' here please)
        var if_url = 'http://myiframecontent.com/';

        // Keep track of the iframe height.
        var if_height;

        // Pass the parent page URL into the Iframe in a meaningful way (this URL could be
        // passed via query string or hard coded into the child page, it depends on your needs).
        var src = if_url + '#' + encodeURIComponent( document.location.href );

        // Append the Iframe into the DOM.
        var iframe = $( '<iframe " src="' + src + '" width="200" height="100" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"><\/iframe>' )
            .appendTo( '#iframe' );

        // Setup a callback to handle the dispatched MessageEvent event. In cases where
        // window.postMessage is supported, the passed event will have .data, .origin and
        // .source properties. Otherwise, this will only have the .data property.
        $.receiveMessage(
            function(e){
                // Get the height from the passsed data.
                var h = Number( e.data.replace( /.*if_height=(\d+)(?:&|$)/, '$1' ) );

                if ( !isNaN( h ) && h > 0 && h !== if_height ) {
                    // Height has changed, update the iframe.
                    iframe.height( if_height = h );
                    // Some user feedback if we want to...
                    $("#ticker").text("has been informed that IFrame contents height is now " + h + " and (re)acted accordingly.");
                }
            }, 
            // An optional origin URL (Ignored where window.postMessage is unsupported).
            if_url 
        );

    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Container <span id="ticker"></span></p>
<div id="iframe"></div>
<p>Container</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this should go to "iframe" site / server B: `http://myiframecontent.com/`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Contents on domain B (http://myiframecontent.com/)</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/cowboy/jquery-postmessage/master/jquery.ba-postmessage.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
   // Get the parent page URL as it was passed in, for browsers that don't support
   // window.postMessage (this URL could be hard-coded).
   var parent_url = decodeURIComponent( document.location.hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) ),
     link;

   // The first param is serialized using $.param (if not a string) and passed to the
   // parent window. If window.postMessage exists, the param is passed using that,
   // otherwise it is passed in the location hash (that's why parent_url is required).
   // The second param is the targetOrigin.
   function setHeight() {
     $.postMessage({ if_height: $('body').outerHeight( true ) }, parent_url, parent );
   };

   // Let's increase height, and inform the parent document of new height, every 3 second
   var i = 1;
   function increaseHeight() {
       $("#iframecontents").append("<p>Increase #" + i + "</p>");
       i = i + 1;
       // Now that the DOM has been set up (and the height should be set) invoke setHeight.
       setHeight();
   };
   var timer = window.setInterval(increaseHeight, 3000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>iframe starts here</p>
<div id="iframecontents"></div>
<p>iframe ends here</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Be aware that in your real-life implementation, in you IFrame (contents) page, you will of course need some kind of event to hook on and call `setHeight()`.